# The import org.apache.olingo.commons.api.format.ODataFormat cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache, odata, olingo

I have tried to run java project using OData Service in Apache Olingo API.

But I'm getting **"import org.apache.olingo.commons.api.format.ODataFormat cannot be resolved"** Error.

I know to import API path for corresponding Java file to solve this issue. But I couldn't found right one. Anyone helps to solve this issue.

The example file path: https://apache.googlesource.com/olingo-odata4/+/Tutorial_P4_Navigation/samples/tutorials/p1_read?autodive=0%2F%2F

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutorial linked by you is based on *4.0.0-beta-03* version of Olingo. `ODataFormat` is not needed anymore.

Instead

```
ODataFormat format = ODataFormat.fromContentType(responseFormat);
ODataSerializer serializer = odata.createSerializer(format);
```

You can just go with

```
ODataSerializer serializer = odata.createSerializer(responseFormat);
```

`responseFormat` is of type `ContentType` in both cases.

Code presented in the official tutorial is more up-to-date: https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/index.html